# how to set the value of textfield which will be used in iterator

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

```
private Integer[] routeId; private String[] routeName;
```

I have declared this array and getter setter. Now I want to set its values in iterator like:

```
Iterator<Object> iter=tManager.getApprovedTourPlan(staffId,9).iterator();  
 tourList=new ArrayList<TourPlan>();  
 int i=0;  while(iter.hasNext())  { 
                Object[] tour = (Object[]) iter.next();   
                TourPlan tp=new TourPlan();    
                tp.setRouteId(0);
                tp.setRouteName("asd");  
                tourList.add(tp);
       }
```

And on jsp I will use:

```
 <s:iterator list="tourList" var="tour"> <s:property
     name="#tour.routeId"> <s:property name="#tour.routeName">
 </s:iterator>
```

But when I set values:

```
tp.setRouteId(0);  
tp.setRouteName("asd");
```

I can't set values because they accept array. Please tell me how to handle that.

Comment: can't you just create an `Integer` array and set it in your `TourPlan`? what is the problem in that?

Comment: Suppose i get 30 records of tourPlan in the said while loop and and i set tp.setRouteId(integerArray); then on jsp each record will have multiple routeId, Isnt it?. And i want one route for one record.

Comment: in that case your approach is wrong.in place of array all you need is `routeid` and `routename`. so i am not sure what the purpose of using array?

Answer (score 1):

From what I get all you need is nested iterators, they'll look something like this

```
<s:iterator value="lstBean" id="lstBean" status="outerStat">
        <s:textfield value="%{name}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].name"/>
        <s:textfield value="%{amt}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].amt"/>
        <s:textfield value="%{id}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].id"/>
        <s:iterator value="%{lstString}" status="myStat">
            <s:textfield name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].lstString[%{#myStat.index}]"/>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
```

and

```
class XBean
{
    private ArrayList<String> lstString=new ArrayList<String>();
    private String name;
    private Double amt;
    private Integer id;
}
```

Examples

http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=10&title=Nested%20Iterators%20Example

http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=11&title=Iterator%20over%20an%20array/list%20of%20objects/beans